# Are noetherian modules over noetherian ring and artinian modules over artinian ring finitely generated?

Tags: modules, noetherian, artinian

We know that [Finitely generated modules over a Noetherian ring are Noetherian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533873/finitely-generated-modules-over-a-noetherian-ring-are-noetherian) and finitely generated modules over a Artinian ring are artinian.

Now I want to know whether the converse is also right, that is: Are noetherian modules over a noetherian ring  finitely generated? Are artinian modules over a artinian ring finitely generated?

To noetherian case, I think it is right: Let $M$ be a left noetherian module over a noetherian ring $R$. Suppose $M$ is not finitely generated, take $m_1 \in M$, then $M_1=Rm_1 \subset M$. Since $M$ is not finitely generated, there is $m_2 \in M$ \ $M_1$,$M_2 :=M_1 +Rm_2$, then $M_1 \subset M_2 $. Take $m_3 \in M$\ $M_2$, $M_3 := M_2 +Rm_3$, then $M_1 \subset M_2 \subset M_3$. Continue this process, we get an infinite increasing chain of submodules of $M$. This contradicts with $M$ noetherian. So $M$ is finitely generated.

I can't make sure the above is right, thank you for checking. Also I don't know whether the artinian case is right or wrong. Thank you for any help.

Comment: [Noetherian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147983/is-every-noetherian-module-finitely-generated) and [Artinian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300418/is-every-artinian-module-over-an-artinian-ring-finitely-generated)

Comment: *Are noetherian modules over a noetherian ring finitely generated?* Noetherian modules over **any ring** are finitely generated. You may have noticed this since your proof is basically the right idea and does not reference anything about $R$ being noetherian. The Artinian case does use different mechanisms. At the linked half-duplicate, you can see two explanations for that.

Comment: Just a quick question, the answer in the link explicitly uses commutativity, is this necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for $1:$ a Noetherian $R$-module $M$ is finitely generated irrespective of whether or not $R$ is Noetherian. This is for the reason you give in the body of the question. Nothing about $R$ is required, as f.g follows from just the ascending chain condition.

The answer for question $2$, is yes, and in fact $M$ is Noetherian, as shown by [hopkin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopkins%E2%80%93Levitzki_theorem).