# If every irreducible elements in Noetherian ring is prime, it is UFD

Tags: principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains

I have problem with the proof of theorem 4 in this [link](https://planetmath.org/everypidisaufd)

It says if $R$ is an Noetherian ring, we construct $\mathbb U$, the set of ideals generated by each element of
$R$ that cannot be written as a product of irreducible elements of $R$.
**then $\mathbb U$ have an maximal element** $(r)$.

But I'm not sure what is mean by the "set of ideals generated by **each** element of $R$"

I think it means $\mathbb U = \{(a) : a \text{ is not a product of irreducibles} \}$
But in that case, how can I make an ascending chain that gives maximal element of $\mathbb U$?

Comment: You don't need to "make an ascending chain". The property of being Noetherian guarantees that any nonempty set of ideals contains a maximal element. You don't need to prove Zorn's Lemma applies to the set $\mathbb{U}$: noetherianness tells you it does (because any ascending chain is finite).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you. Then I'll search for that property.

Comment: [Here's a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/148044/742) that (i) all submodules are finitely generated; (ii) all ascending chains of submodules stabilizer; and (iii) any nonempty collection of submodules has maximal elements; are equivalent. If $R$ is noetherian, then any finitely genreated $R$-module is noetherian; and $R$ is a finitely generated module over itself. Alternatively, just do the proofs with "ideals" substituting "submodules".